# AssertionError: <bound method object> returned during python unittest and properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, properties

I was taking a python test and am unclear on something that appeared in the test.  The test used test driven development, so we were given a file with unittest assertions calling into a module we needed to create.  So, I'm unable to change how the calls are made in the test file.

Here is the basics of the two files that focus on my question:

test_yahtzee.py:

```
  from yahtzee import Roll, Type
      import yahtzee
    
  class TestYahtzee(unittest.TestCase):
    # ... 
    # tests
    # ... 
      def testFindUpperBest(self):
         '''Finds best scoring opportunity from upper part of scorepad'''
         self.assertEqual(Type.SIXES,  Roll(1, 6, 1, 2, 3).up_best)
```

in yahtzee.py:

```
class Type(Enum):
    SIXES = 1
    #...
    # more enum values
    #

class Roll():

    def __init__(self, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5) -> None:
      pass

    @property # BUT WHAT IF THIS WEREN'T HERE?
    def up_best(self) -> Type:
      print('Found me!')
      ## Will return a Type later ...
```

This is the part that confuses me:

Note that the test_yahtzee.py file doesn't use an instance of Roll and instead looks like the unittest module must bind the <Class.fun> method (i.e., Roll(...).up_best) to something it can call ... again I can't change this file.

I don't understand how this syntax interacts with the ways I can define the class's method.  Here are the four possibilities when using python3 -m unittest test_yahtzee.py

**Can someone explain what is happening in these four cases so I understand the nuances better?**

| yahtzee.py | test_yahtze.py | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| with @property as above | Roll(...).up_best | 'Found me', test passes |
| no @property | Roll(...).up_best | AssertionError: <Type.SIXES> != <bound method Roll.up_best of ... |
| with @property as above | Roll(...).up_best() | 'Found me', but 'Type' object is not callable |
| no @property | Roll(...).up_best() | 'Found me', test passes |

The way the test file is written ... it seems to assume this must be a getter with a @property attribute since that's the ONLY possibility that seems to function?

Comment: What is `up_best`? You showed us `best_upper` only.

Comment: apologies, editing wasn't as finished as I had thought.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that the test_yahtzee.py file doesn't use an instance of Roll and instead looks like the unittest module must bind the <Class.fun> method (i.e., Roll(...).up_best) to something it can call ... again I can't change this file.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the test_yahtzee.py file doesn't use an instance of Roll". The test *is* using an instance of Roll. `Roll(1, 6, 1, 2, 3)` creates an instance of Roll.

As for your question, you are correct that the test code is assuming `up_best` is a property on the class.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) for a property states:

> Calling property() is a succinct way of building a data descriptor that triggers a function call upon access to an attribute.

Basically, you can present a function as an attribute.

In the test code, `Roll(1, 6, 1, 2, 3).up_best` creates an instance of Roll and then accesses the `up_best` attribute on it. Accessing `up_best` returns a Type and presumably `Type.SIXES` is also a Type.

I'll try to explain the four cases you enumerated.

#### With @property and Roll().up_best

Here you have a match where the method decorated with `@property` is to be called by accessing an attribute and `Roll().up_best` is accessing by an [attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-attribute). This works fine.

#### With no @property and Roll().up_best

Here you have a mismatch because `up_best` is now a normal [method](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method) since you removed `@property` and it has to be accessed by being called, not by an attribute. . A method is a callable function and `Roll().up_best` is accessing `up_best` as an attribute. You get an error.

#### With @property and Roll().up_best()

Here you have another mismatch because `up_best` is a property which has to be accessed by an attribute and `up_best()` is attempting to call it as a method. You get an error because Type is not callable.

#### With no @property and Roll().up_best()

Here you have a match again. Since you removed the `@property` decorator, `up_best` is now a normal method which has to be called and `Roll().up_best()` is calling `up_best` as a function. This works fine.

Hope this helps.